# Real-Time Slack clone with AngularFire not working even after changes done

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I tried to work this tutorial  https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial#authenticating-users-using-angularfire

And the problem i have is with Firebase Authentication. In code there are no errors but it doesn't want to connect with base and error is:

Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

I even updated the code to match with the new firebase 3.x.x syntax still i can seem to make it work.

Comment: Please post the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Frank van Puffelen i have tried to clone the entire code that is in the link that i have given...the problem persists even after the updation of the syntax of 3.x.x..but I dont understand y...the code is distributed among many files and I dnt seem to know where exactly the problem is happening